# Ruby - Case Statement help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a case statement that goes a little something like this:

```
case @type
 when "normal"

 when "return"

 else
end
```

That works fine but I want to add in something like:

```
case @type
 when "normal"

 when "return"

 when @type length > 1, and contains no spaces

 else
end
```

Is that valid / safe?

Comment: `@type length > 1` is invalid, perhaps you meant `@type.length > 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you aren't matching against the value of @type then don't include it right after the case statement, but rather in the when clauses:

```
case 
  when @type=="normal" then "blah"

  when @type=="return" then "blah blah"

  when (@type.length>1 and !@type.include?(' ')) then "blah blah blah"

  else 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this?

```
@type[/^[^\s]{2,}$/]
```

Comment: @mu is too short, yes, i know. I purposely use `\s` in case the definition of "spaces" is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a [regex in a `when`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#S5):

```
case @type
    when 'normal'      then 'it is normal'
    when 'return'      then 'it is return'
    when /^[^ ][^ ]+$/ then 'it is long enough and has no spaces'
    else                    'it is something else'
end
```

The `[^ ]` means "anything but a space" and `[^ ][^ ]+` means "anything but a space followed by one or more characters that are not a space", anchoring the regex at both ends ensures that there won't be any spaces at all.

Comment: This answer is more precise, deleted mine